# Linux & Bash Chromosomes sorting files

Tags: linux, sort, bioinformatics

I need to combine all the files with genomic data in that particular way. It means it should be sorted first by numbers then alphabetically. The names of files are:

```
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.1.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.2.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.3.fa.gz 
etc.
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.11.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.13.fa.gz
etc.
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.X.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.Y.fa.gz
```

I need to do it in bash as easy as possible; with no scripts etc.. I try to use `sort -V` and the others but it's still doesn't work. Any ideas? 8)

Comment: What is the end goal though?  They should be sorted and then concatenated into a single file?

Comment: Sort the file *names* or their contents? What pieces of the filenames, or what are sample contents?

Comment: What is the output of: `ls -1 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.*.fa.gz | sort -V`. -1, distinct from -l.

Comment: @Jesse_b Oh. For me it returns the expected output - what OS/shell are you running, just out of curiosity.

Comment: The goal is single file, doesn't matter zipped or not. But the order is important inside the output file

Comment: @Kahn, the output of your version give the "X" at the beginning. It should be at the end

Comment: @Kahn: It seems that only works if you specify the field to be sorted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ls | sort -V -d
```

It returns

```
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.1.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.9.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.13.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.19.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.X.fa.gz
```

I tried experimenting with `-V` option because it should natively handle "X" at the end and when you remove the dot before the character where numbering starts, it works. I wonder why though :)

EDIT:
The reason why `-V` option does not sort properly is given on GNU Coreutils's website (firstly, it is only dedicated for numbered/indexed versions.

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the `zsh` shell,

```sh
print -l Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.*.fa.gz(n)
```

would print the files in the order you want:

```
$ print -l Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.*.fa.gz(n)
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.1.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.2.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.3.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.4.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.5.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.6.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.7.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.8.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.9.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.10.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.11.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.12.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.13.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.14.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.15.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.16.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.17.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.18.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.19.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.20.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.21.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.22.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.X.fa.gz
Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.Y.fa.gz
```

The `(n)` at the end sorts the names resulting from the glob match by decimal integers.  The `X` and `Y` are left in lexicographical order at the end.

To combine these into a single file:

```sh
cat Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.*.fa.gz(n) >Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.combined.fa.gz
```

Note that I'm choosing a name that does not match the pattern, and that the `gzip` format allows this type of concatenation (uncompressing the compressed combined file would give you the combined data from all combined file).  If you have compressed this with [`bgzip`](https://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html) then I *think* that you still should be ok.

Note too that if you have an `M` or `Un` chromosome (mitochondrial and unplaced scaffolds), these may mess up the sorting somewhat as you usually want these at the end.

You also get this sorting order with `sort -t. -k5,5 -V` (does "version sort" on the fifth dot-delimited field), while `sort -V` (without specifying a sorting field) would sort on `38` and not the chromosome numbers.

---

In `bash`:

```bash
printf '%s\0' Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.*.fa.gz |
sort -z -t. -k5,5 -V |
xargs -0 cat >Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.combined.fa.gz
```

This creates a list of all the relevant filenames and pipes them off to the `sort` command (which I have already explained).  After sorting, `xargs` reads the sorted names and calls `cat` on them to concatenate the data.  The output is written to a new file as in the `zsh` example.

Throughout the pipeline, the filenames are treated as nul-terminated strings.

Comment: The result is ok, however, I'm limited to vanilla bash.

Comment: @Krzyztopher You can't even use `zsh -c 'cat Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.chromosome.*.fa.gz(n)' >file` in bash?

Comment: no, just common bash without any packages

Comment: @Krzyztopher Then you could possibly use the `sort` command that I mentioned at the end somehow. Though I find it odd that you're on a system without the `zsh` shell...

Comment: let's say I have no admin right to install zsh and my Ubuntu does not come with zsh installed

Comment: @Krzyztopher See updated answer. As a side note, `zsh` can easily be compiled and installed in one's home directory, but I understand if that's too much work if all you want to do is sort a list of filenames.